# ¿No se como aumentar información que viene de un bucle php?

Tags: php

Tengo esto en el codigo

```
 // ingreso del id del producto
 if(isset($_GET['p'])){
 $_SESSION['producto']['id'] = $_GET['p']; 
 }
 //ingreso de la cantidad
 if(isset($_GET['c'])){
 $_SESSION['producto']['can'] = $_GET['c']; 
 }

 for ($i=0; $i < count($_SESSION['producto']); $i+=2 ){

   $cab = $_SESSION['producto']['can'];

  $query = mysqli_query($conect,'SELECT * FROM Productos WHERE 
  id='.$_SESSION['producto']['id'].'');
  while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$fila['Nombre'].'</td>';
            echo '<center><td>';
            echo '<center><input type="number" name="ja" class="la" 
            value="'.$cab.'""></center>';
            echo '</td></center>';
         }
```

con eso logro que se muestre la informacion que viene de p y c pero necesito que a medida que de click en añadir la información aumente y no solo cambie

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: "pero necesito que a medida que de click en añadir la información aumente y no solo cambie" podrías explicarte mejor ? no entendí nada !

Comment: Justo como comenta @CamiloVasquez necesitamos saber que quieres hacer en esa línea que él cito.

Comment: ahorita ingerso la cantidad y pongo añadir y en sumario solo me sale la informacion que esta pero si doy clcik de nuevo se cmabia por la nueva y lo que necesito es que si doy otro click se quede la primera y se ponga la segunda y asi sucesivamente....

Answer (score 0):

Prueba algo así como esto, no lo he probado y lo he picado directo aquí, pero la idea es poner los productos en un array, porque tal como lo haces tu, reemplazas cada vez el contenido de la session:

```
// ingreso del id del producto
$producto_actual = count($_SESSION['producto']);
if(isset($_GET['p'])){
    $_SESSION['producto'][$producto_actual]['id'] = $_GET['p']; 
}
//ingreso de la cantidad
if(isset($_GET['c'])){
    $_SESSION['producto'][$producto_actual]['can'] = $_GET['c']; 
}

foreach($_SESSION['producto'] as $k => $producto) {
    $cab = $producto['can'];
    $query = mysqli_query($conect,'SELECT * FROM Productos WHERE id=' . $producto['id'] . '');
    while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$fila['Nombre'].'</td>';
        echo '<center><td>';
        echo '<center><input type="number" name="ja" class="la" value="' . $cab . '""></center>';
        echo '</td></center>';
}
```